# get_comments_number() returns 0

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, comments, comment-form

I am customizing a theme that has the following code to display comments:

```
if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h2 class="comments-title">
        <?php
            printf( // WPCS: XSS OK.
                esc_html( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'kadabra' ) ),
                number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
                '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>'
            );
        ?>
    </h2>
```

however it always shows the following:

```
0 thoughts on “Post title”
```

even though I have several comments and the `if ( have_comments() ) :` part is passed. Any ideas?

PS: wp_debug is enabled and show no errors as well.

Comment: try `get_comments_number($post)` maybe? although if `have_comments` and `get_the_title` are both working without a post object/id in them then that should as well.  do you still get 0 if you `var_dump` comments_number?

Comment: Are you running the code inside [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)?

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at the source there seems to be three possibilities:

1. `get_post()` returned *falsy* value, so current post context is invalid in some way.
2. `$post->comment_count` is `0`.
3. `get_comments_number` filter is being used to adjust the output.

Most commonly it would be case 1/2 with something interfering with global post context, dump `get_post()` at the point and see if it contains expected instance.

Answer (score 0):

What probably happened is that you did not approve comments in admin panel.

When you only have comments that are "pending" you still pass `have_comments()`, but those comments are not counted.